# Non-U.S. Citizen Backpacker Working Remotely for U.S. Company

Tags: income-tax, bank-account, non-resident, working-abroad

I've worked full-time in the United States for a software development company with a F-1 Visa (OPT). Now, I am going to be traveling and working remotely for that company.

#### Facts:

- I am not a U.S. citizen
- I will be traveling to many countries but I am planning on staying maximum of 6 weeks in each country.
- I am currently a full-time status paying federal taxes as well as California taxes.
- As of now, I'm thinking of traveling indefinitely and no plans to settle in one country

#### Now, I have some questions regarding taxes:

1. To whom do I need to pay my taxes?
2. Do I need to pay my tax in the United States at all? If so, do I need to pay Social Security and other social coverage? Do I need to pay my tax to California where the company is located?
3. What benefit do I get from having a "contractor" title as opposed to "full-time" in terms of taxes? (All the perks such as vacation days will be the same)
4. Should I get paid to my personal savings account in the U.S. or in another country? What are some benefits and restrictions?

*Thanks a lot in advance.*

Answer (score 2):

> To whom do I need to pay my taxes?

To each country you'll be working in. In addition, you should check the laws of your country of citizenship, some have rules that define their citizens as tax residents unless they're tax residents elsewhere.

If you're moving to a different country every 6 weeks - you may end up with paying taxes to 8-9 different countries each year.

Keep in mind that many countries forbid employment for tourists, so you'll be very limited about where you can go with this. Unless you want to break the law, that is, but that is a dangerous game to play. Once you get arrested/deported due to an immigration law violation, you're likely to be deported to your country of citizenship and will require visas to many other places even if you're exempt due to citizenship (for example, if you get deported from any Schengen country, you'll be required to get a visa for any other Schengen country after that).

Also, in many countries you're required to register for, collect and pay VAT on services provided.

> Do I need to pay my tax in the United States at all? If so, do I need
>   to pay Social Security and other social coverage? Do I need to pay my
>   tax to California where the company is located?

No, but you may end up being considered California resident even if you're not US resident for Federal tax purposes (as is the case when you're on F1 OPT).

> What benefit do I get from having a "contractor" title as opposed to
>   "full-time" in terms of taxes? (All the perks such as vacation days
>   will be the same)

Depending on the country you're working in this may have different implications. However, it is very unlikely that you'll be able to pull this off as an employee since it will require your employer to register in all the countries you'll be working at and I doubt they'd want to do that.

> Should I get paid to my personal savings account in the U.S. or in
>   another country? What are some benefits and restrictions?

Depending on the countries you'll be working at and the countries of your citizenship there may be some limitations. You'll have to check that.

---

To clarify certain issues with regards to taxes that came up in the comments:

1. Employment defined: providing personal services for a pay.
2. Income source: Income is sourced to the country where it is earned. Income is earned in the country where the services are provided. Services are provided where the provider is physically present.
3. Foreign income vs. Domestic income: Income that is not sourced to the country (i.e.: not earned for services you provided while being in that country), is considered foreign by that country.
4. General rules of income taxation: With the notable exception of the US, most countries tax **everyone** on income sourced to them, and **residents** on worldwide income. The US considers its citizens to be its residents regardless of where they physically reside.
5. Why is this different from a writer answering emails: writer doesn't provide services.
6. Why is this different from a 1%-er answering emails: 1%-er doesn't provide services.
7. Why is this different from a contractor answering emails: it is not.
8. Why contractors don't end up in jail for answering emails: tax treaties protect them in these cases. Most tax treaties between most countries exempt short periods of work from the sourcing definitions.
9. Why tax treaties won't help the OP: he plans on not being resident *anywhere*, tax treaties only protect **residents** of one country from the tax laws in the other.
10. Why people don't like hearing this (or similar) answers: because people don't like hearing that they have to pay taxes. Please don't downvote this answer if you're one of these people, its not my fault that you have to pay taxes.

With regards to immigration - talk to an immigration adviser/attorney for each country you're considering working in. For most - working without an explicit authorization would be against the local law. For definition of working see #1 above, however many countries (including the US) don't consider you being paid or not as a factor.

Comment: Are there actually countries where "forbid employment for tourists" extends to people who simply are present in the country while they do work for an out-of-country employer?  It's not totally clear from the question, but I was interpreting the OPs situation as akin to, say, a writer or consultant traveling around while sending emails and the like back home.  If this counts as employment then many one-percenters who answer work emails while lounging poolside in the Bahamas may be vulnerable to prosecution :-).

Comment: @BrenBarn I'm not familiar with any country which allows employment for tourists without an explicit authorization. There's a different between "answering emails" and being full-time employee. If the main goal is to lounge poolside and you answer occasional emails once every half a day - you're on vacation. If the main goal is to be a full time employee but not a tax resident - you're breaking the law.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response. When you mention "employment", do you mean working for a company and getting paid in the country I am staying in? Then, I would need an explicit authorization (i.e. visa). But, if I am getting paid in the U.S. from a U.S. based company, like @BrenBarn said, how would that be illegal? Is there some reference you could point me to? Thanks again.

Comment: @user013948 you said you won't be in the US. How are you going to get paid in the US? You'll go there to get paid? I'm not sure I understand. If you mean that the actual bank account is in the US - that's of no consequence. **You** are being paid, not your bank account. It will be illegal, because BrenBran misunderstands the difference between "illegal but not caught" and "legal".

Comment: As to references - you're discribing a typical "nomad worker" situation. Most of the people in such a scenario **are** in fact breaking the law in the countries they're working at. Both immigration and tax law.

Comment: @littleadv right. I will not be in the US. I can get paid if my bank account is in the U.S. Could you provide a reference for what you mean by "illegal"?

Comment: @user013948 as I said - you'll have to tell me which countries you're going to be breaking the law at so that I can point you to the specific laws you'll be breaking.

Comment: Ok. Let's say I'm traveling to Japan

Comment: "*However, if the non-permanent resident has the amount paid outside Japan relating to domestic source income in the year,
the payments made from abroad to Japan are first deemed to be remittance relating to domestic source income*" That's on page 3 here: http://www.nta.go.jp/tetsuzuki/shinkoku/shotoku/tebiki2014/pdf/43.pdf, read the whole document about the taxation rules in Japan. As to working without visa: see here: http://tokyo-foreigner.jsite.mhlw.go.jp/english/seekers_1/spec/spec_1a.html I'm sure you can do similar Google searches yourself for any other country.

Comment: I'd appreciate the downvoter to explain what is **incorrect**. Please don't downvote just because you disagree with the reality of the world.

Comment: It's worth noting that the letter of the law is not the same as the reality of the world.  The reality of the world is that many people do this.  (I didn't downvote, though.)

Comment: @BrenBarn but the OP asked about the letter of the law. He asked whom to pay taxes to and whether being paid in this or that way or for this or that kind of work matters. If the OP wants to work illegally and not to pay taxes - he doesn't need our permission.

Comment: @littleadv It's notable to compare the "letter of the law" and the "reality of the law", and that I did not explicitly state that at the beginning. What I meant was how do writers, programmers etc deal with taxes if they are traveling and not getting paid in that country while working. It technically sounds illegal to do so in some countries, but I was looking more into some common methods that people do that is still safe.

Comment: (+1) It's a minor quibble but technically, the bit about Schengen countries is not entirely accurate. If your citizenship allows you to visit the area without a visa, you cannot get a short-stay Schengen visa under any circumstances nor are you ever required to get one. If you get deported, you might also get a ban and such a ban would indeed cover the whole area but then the only way around it is appealing the ban to the country that issued it. Applying for a visa would still be impossible and unnecessary, either during the duration of the ban or after it ended.

Comment: @Relaxed I'm not sure I agree with this. To the best of my understanding, all the "visa-free" privileges do not extended to persons who have been deported in the past.

Comment: @littleadv That's the way the US visa waiver program works, maybe the UK too but you can read the [Schengen](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32006R0562) [regulations](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810), you won't find anything like that. You can be banned, you can be denied entry but there is no intermediate category like “not banned but required to get a visa”. If you don't need a visa based on your citizenship, the only thing you can do is try your luck at the border, you can't apply for a visa as a sort of advance test.

Comment: @Relaxed whatever, it really isn't relevant at all to the answer.

Comment: @littleadv Sure, that's why I upvoted it and said it's a minor quibble ;-) But since you mentioned it, I figured you might want to amend that sentence or replace it with another example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, OP is an F1/ OPT student and could fall within the Non-Resident Alien category which means that your tax filing is a little bit complicated from a Resident Alien or US citizen. 
US citizens and Residents have to report their domestic and worldwide income but I think you don't qualify for the significance presence test. You are permitted to file for taxes as a resident If you've been in the US for 5 consecutives years as an F1 student. I'm not sure you meet this test.
Ok, enough of the immigration talk, lets get back to taxes! because you're a non-resident alien in the US, you would have report to every country you visit and work .
check with the tax laws of every country you visit and be sure not to fall into any tax evasion trap.
In case you decide to report all your income in the US, make sure you're exempted from social security and medicare contributions. Visit the IRS Website and look for publication 519.

Comment: In fact, I have been in the U.S. for longer than 5 years with a F1 visa, so that would allow me to file for taxes as a resident. Does that mean I need to pay social security and other welfare taxes? What about the California state? I appreciate your help.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to employment **after** his OPT is finished.